# Form validation is not working

Tags: javascript, html, validation

Here is my code :

when after i entered name and email the form validation isn't performing.What should i do to validate the user entered data.And i would to like to move to another jsp page of name start.jsp when i click on Participate Kindly help me to get rid of this and please tell me what and why itsn't working..

```
 <html>
<head>
<title>Aptitude Competition Online</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
<script language="javascript">
function isEmpty(str) { 
if(str=="" )
{
return true;
} else return false;
}
function validate() {  
var nam = document.form[0].name.value; 
var ema = document.form[0].email.value; 
 if(isEmpty(nam)) 
  { 
       alert(Name should be filled out"); 
       document.form[0].name.focus;
       return false;
  }
 else if(isEmpty(ema) 
  {
       alert(E-mail should be filled out"); 
       document.form[0].email.focus;  
       return false;  
  } 
  else {  
       return true; 
       } 
       } 
  </script> 
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="header1">
  <font id="font1">Aptitude Quiz</font>
  </div>
  <div id="email">
  <div id="inside">
  <font id="font2">Welcome to Aptitude Quiz</font><br><br><br>
   <form name="form">
   Name : <input type="text" name="name"><br><br>
   E-mail : <input type="text" name="email"><br><br>
   <input name="Participate" type="button" value="Participate"          onClick="validate()"><br><br>
   </form>
   </div>
    </div>
     <div id="footer">
      Contact Us : gmail@name.com 
      </div>
       </body>
      </html>
```

Comment: What error are you getting in console?

Comment: There's several syntax errors, missing quotes, `document.forms` etc.

Answer (score 2):

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        function isEmpty(str)
        {
            if (str == "")
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        function validate()
        {
            var nam = document.form.name.value
            var ema = document.form.email.value;
            if (isEmpty(nam))
            {
                alert("Name should be filled out");
                document.form.name.focus();
                return false;
            }
            else if (isEmpty(ema))
            {
                alert("E-mail should be filled out");
                document.form.email.focus();
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }
        } 
    </script>
```

**Change only the script part**

Answer (score 1):

Change as per this

```
 <form name="form" method = "post" onsubmit = "return validate();">
  Name : <input type="text" name="name"><br><br>
  E-mail : <input type="text" name="email"><br><br>
  <button name="Participate" value="Submit" type = "submit"><br><br>
  </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Aptitude Competition Online</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
<script type="text/javascript">
function validate()
{  
var nam = document.forms[0].name.value; 
var ema = document.forms[0].email.value; 
if(nam == "") 
  { 
       alert("Name should be filled out"); 
       //document.forms[0].name.focus;
       document.getElementById("name").focus();
       return false;
  }
 else if(ema =="") 
  {
       alert("E-mail should be filled out"); 
       //document.forms[0].email.focus;
        document.getElementById("email").focus();
       return false;  
  } 
  else {  
       return true; 
       } 
}

  </script> 
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="header1">
  <font id="font1">Aptitude Quiz</font>
  </div>
  <div id="email">
  <div id="inside">
  <font id="font2">Welcome to Aptitude Quiz</font><br><br><br>
   <form name="form">
   Name : <input type="text" name="name" id="name"><br><br>
   E-mail : <input type="text" name="email" id="email"><br><br>
   <input name="Participate" type="button" value="Participate" onClick="validate()"><br><br>
   </form>
   </div>
    </div>
     <div id="footer">
      Contact Us : gmail@name.com 
      </div>
       </body>
      </html>
```

Comment: What is the actual problem with that code ?       document.forms[0].name.focus; is also a method in javascript to focus the text area right

Comment: The main proplem with that code is '<script language="javascript">'

Comment: even i changed it to <script type="text/javascript"> it is not working.